# Convergence of a set sequence actually means equal?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Very naive question as I get started with probability measure theory using Jacod and Protter's *Probability Essentials*. In Chapter 2 the limit function $$\unicode{x1D7D9}_A(\omega)=\left\{\begin{array}{l}1\text{ if }\omega\in A\\0\text{ if }\omega\not\in A\end{array}\right.$$ is defined where $\omega\in\Omega$ the state space and $A\in\mathcal{A}$ the $\sigma$-algebra that is the event space. The authors call the sequence of sets $A_n\in\mathcal{A}$ converging to $A$ if $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\unicode{x1D7D9}_{A_n}(\omega)=\unicode{x1D7D9}_A(\omega)$$ for all $\omega\in\Omega$.

This got me thinking: since limit existence means that $\forall\varepsilon>0$, $\exists N_\varepsilon>0$ such that $|\unicode{x1D7D9}_{A_n}(\omega)-\unicode{x1D7D9}_A(\omega)|<\varepsilon$ whenever $n>N_\varepsilon$, by choosing $\varepsilon<1$, we have the same result except that $\unicode{x1D7D9}_{A_n}(\omega)\equiv\unicode{x1D7D9}_A(\omega)$ since $\unicode{x1D7D9}$ can be either $0$ or $1$ not anything in between.

In the case when $|\Omega|<\infty$, the convergence criterion actually says that there needs to exist $N\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ such that when $n>N$, $\unicode{x1D7D9}_{A_n}(\omega)\equiv\unicode{x1D7D9}_A(\omega)$ for all $N$ and all $\omega\in\Omega$?

So, does the convergence of sets imply that they have to actually equal at some point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try a concrete example
$ \mathbb 1_{[0,1-1/n]}$, $\omega \in [0,1]$. Your observation is that, for each $\omega$, $\mathbb 1_{A_n}(\omega)$ is eventually $\mathbb 1_A(\omega)$. Yes, but this does not hold uniformly in $\omega$.

Comment: Uniform if $\Omega$ is finite right? Thanks for the prompt reply.

Comment: @SekotsReivan yep. No problem :)

Comment: @SekotsReivan maybe its worth mentioning that I was slightly confused when you wrote $|\Omega| < \infty$, because I thought this was assumed since you were talking about a probability measure (that is, I assumed that this meant you were using a finite measure space!)

Comment: So in the book, $\Omega$ denotes the state space, the set of subsets of whom is used to generate a $\sigma$-algebra. I just started the book, not sure what a finite measure is sorry..

Comment: @SekotsReivan yeah I know, but I just wanted  to tell you that the notation $|A|$ has been used for measure as well. A probability measure is an example of a finite measure (because the probability measure of the entire state space $\Omega$ is 1 which is finite) but don't sweat it, you'll get to it eventually